# Ember-Cli vendor.js initial download - Showing a loading message

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

## What is the ember-cli way of displaying a static message to indicate that the emper-app itself (vendor.js) is loading (being downloaded)?

### Current situation

- Index.html is blank pre vendor.js download

### Goal

- Display something to the user while vendor.js is downloading to avoid making them leave the page while its loading.

### Solution idea (not yet tested, not yet known if it's a good solution)

1. Create a named div in the index.html file
2. Hide it on ember initialization

Comment: create an initializer that runs once all other initializers have ran?

Comment: yeah, that would be a way to implement the solution idea. Any nice way of making an initializer once the others have run btw?

Comment: you can set before and after so I guess you can have a pop there - no guarantees it will run before all the 3rd party initializers have ran but i'd start there

Comment: Seems I need to name all the other initializers to accomplish that. I resorted to invoking the "hide the div" code in my applicationroutes renderTemplate before calling this._super

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "loading" route in ember?
You can place any template you want to display during loading into "**app/routes/loading.hbs**".
If you are using pods, place it into "**app/pods/loading/template.hbs**".
If you want more detailed instructions, see:
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I meant the loading of the vendor.js file containing the ember code (assuming ember-cli project)